# Why do we re-implement parent interface of derived interface on class which implement derived interface

Tags: c#, interface

I was studying about UOW pattern on [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and saw following code

```
interface IStudentRepository: IDisposable
{
    void SomeMethod();
}
// Interface Implementaion

class StudentRepository: IStudentRepository, IDisposable
{
   public void SomeMethod(){}
   public void Dispose(){}
}
```

Now my question is why do we re-implement parent interface of a derived interface on a class which implements derived interface? For instance, IStudentRepository interface derived from IDisposable interface but when we implement IStudentRepository interface on StudentRepository class we implement IDisposable as well in addition to IStudentRepository interface.

1. What benefits will it provide?
2. which problem does it solve?
3. Or it is totally unnecessary/redundant?

**NOTE:** I have tried this code without reimplementing IDisposable again and the tried casting back and forward; everything worked as it works with re-implementation.

Comment: It would solve `IStudentRepository` dropping `IDisposable` in the future, but that's kind of dicey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying `IDisposable` on the class that implements `IStudentRepository` is redundant. It has no effect at all.

Comment: @mkArtak The only reason I think of is code readability. Assume someone is looking at StudentRepository he can tell by looking at the class that it's disposable instead of going to interface definition to find out this fact.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to do:

```
class StudentRepository: IStudentRepository, IDisposable { }
```

Just write:

```
class StudentRepository: IStudentRepository { }
```

If you view this in *Resharper* it will tell you that stating `IDisposable` again is redundant.

[image]

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Guess you never did any UML

Comment: Very little. Anyway, the term used in .NET (and Java, and many OO languages) is "implement". See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx: "An interface contains definitions for a group of related functionalities that a class or a struct can **implement**."

Comment: @ThomasLevesque the term in UML is **realise**, which applies to any language

Comment: but we're talking about C# here, not UML ;). Anyway, it doesn't matter, since your answer no longer mentions this, and my first comment somehow disappeared...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque thanks, agreed.  I realised that I was going off topic in the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few reasons this might be a good idea:

- Some inheritance-checking algorithms, especially reflection-based, will fail to discover inherited types in certain scenarios, like parent interfaces. This can be a bug or expected behavior (inheritance chains can be quite long, hurting performance of graph-walkers or other reflective type-checking algorithms). In these cases, if you need to be sure the method will figure out that the object is IDisposable quickly, then reimplement.
- The parent interface might be refactored to remove the Disposable implementation, but the child class will still require it. As chris said in his comment, this isn't a great reason; once an object implements IDisposable it's fairly problematic to remove it from the parent but keep the implementation in the child classes.
- It reminds developers perusing the source code that the object is IDisposable. It's not obvious at a glance that IStudentRepositories are IDisposable, but if this is central to the preferred usage (i.e. the repository should be the focus of a `using` block), then every piece of information helps.

It is, as you've found, not necessary though; if you remove IDisposable from StudentRepository, the class is still IDisposable due to the inheritance on IStudentRepository.

Comment: The first reason is wrong. It makes no difference at all for reflection.

Comment: I beg to differ. If you have an algorithm that inspects the inherited types of an object, then walks those to find their parents and so on, with the objective being to search for a particular parent type, you'll find that type faster the closer it is in the inheritance tree to the entry object.

Comment: OK, maybe I misunderstand what you're talking about. Could you give an example? Because as far as I can tell, the compiler generates exactly the same type with or without the repetition of `IDisposable` (at least I haven't been able to find any difference)

Answer (score 0):

There is one reason I can think of, where that would make sense.

The client of the interface (StudentRepository) has disposable members, which it would like to dispose of too. And it re-implements the IDisposable interface to be protected from future breaking changes on the IStudentRepository interface. In other words, may in the future the IStudentRepository not be IDisposable, there would be no change required on the client side.